# Differentiable structure where the covering is actually a partition.

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

By differentiable structure, I mean a collection of injections of n-th Euclidean space to some set $M$, where the domains are open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the images cover $M$, and mappings from non-empty intersections of the images are smooth.

I am adding a twist, that the covering is actually a partition, so the second condition of a differentiable structure is true in a vacuum. I am not questioning that this is in fact a smooth manifold, since it is.

My question is, what can we say about such a manifold? I thought that maybe it is always diffeomorphic (there exists a smooth mapping with smooth inverse) to some subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, more concretely, the space we get by union of all domains of the injections. So I tried to construct such a diffeomorphism, but got stuck trying to prove that the domains are also a partition of some subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and after the fact I see no reason as to why they should be. Without domains being a partition, defining a diffeomorphism becomes difficult. Maybe there is Choice involved? Not sure.

Also, what other properties can be derived from the hypothesis of the covering being a partition?

It seems more of a set-theoretic question than a topology question, unless the fact that the domains being open plays a role, which as far as I can see, it does not.

As an example, take $M = \{ f_t \}_{t \neq 0}$ where $f_t (x) = tx$, and cover it by $F_+(t) = f_t, t>0$ and $F_-(t) = f_t, t<0$. I split up $\mathbb{R}^* = \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ on purpose, to make it even clearer that change of parameters holds in a vacuum. As is, $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^*$.

Comment: $M$ will be homeomorphic / diffeomorphic to a disjoint union of open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$. However, there is no reason for the domains of the charst to be disjoint: think of $M = \cup_{n \in \Bbb N} (\{n\}\times(-1,1))$ and $\varphi_n\colon (-1,1) \to M$ given by $\varphi_n(x) = (n,x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the example. How do I go about constructing the diffeomorphism though?

Comment: Show that the image of the charts are both open and closed. Up to assuming that the domains of the charts are connected, you will end up showing that the images of the charts are precisely the connected components of $M$. The rest follows easily, since a topological space is the disjoint union of its connected components

Comment: Actually, there is a shorter (but very similar) proof. Show that the map $M \to \cup_{\alpha\in A}(\{\alpha\}\times U_{\alpha})$ which sends $x$ to $(\alpha,\varphi_{\alpha}^{-1}(x))$ where $\alpha$ is the unique index such that $x\in \varphi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha})$, is a diffeomorphism. As a corollary, you obtain that $\alpha$ is at most countable if $M$ is assumed second countable, which is generally included in the definition of manifolds

Comment: That's very interesting, thank you for your time.